# Facebook like problem - same count for all post

Tags: facebook-like

I use this code to generate dinamicaly the like buttons:

```
<? $artlink = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='.$artlink.'&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none;margin-top:12px;overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:24px;"></iframe>
```

Every post has the same count of likes. What is the problem?
I have Joomla 1.5.20, sef404 2.1, view and module caching. If I turn off the caching, it can't help.

My site:
[valovilag4.com](http://www.valovilag4.com/)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encode your $artlink, I think the "special" characters are causing the problem.

Try this:

```
$artlink=urlencode($artlink);
```

Or use the XFBML version of the like widget.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem. I was using the exact same method to output the href of my page to the like button as Dean was, so I was really hopeful this solution would work for me also. I changed it to use urlencode() and nothing changed; all the pages on my site have the same like count (which is way higher than it should be). I am using the FBML method; here is my code: `<fb:like href="<?php echo urlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )?>" show_faces="false" width="450" action="recommend" font="arial" colorscheme="dark"></fb:like>` -- any suggestions?